# Есть ли глагол "забоготворить"? Как выразить "начнут боготворить" одним словом?

Tags: глаголы, времена

В частности, интересует фраза: "они забоготворят (начнут боготворить в будущем) что-либо"

Comment: Близкий смысл можно получить  с глаголом сов. вида "обоготворят" (подразумевается, что единожды обоготворив, продолжат боготворить).

Answer (score 2):

**Забоготворить – сленг, ненормативное слово.**

Примеры употребления:

Тебя так запиарить, и тебя забоготворят (= захвалят).

Про натянуть корону и ждать когда тебя забоготворят (= начнут боготворить) – это не ко мне.

Также надо учитывать, что приставка ЗА **многозначная**: заиграть – начать играть, захвалить – перехвалить.

Answer (score 1):

У глагола *боготворить* нет будущего времени. Для выражения будущего времени нужно использовать вспомогательный глагол *быть*: **будут боготворить**.

Глагол *забоготворить* не существует. Можно сказать *начать боготворить*. В будущем времени: *они начнут (станут) боготворить*.

Comment: так и знал, спасибо